# How to include wp-load.php from any location?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin which calls a stand-alone php script (`myAjax.php`) via a `jQuery.ajax()` script inside the plugin.

I need to place the following code into the `myAjax.php` file:

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

if (!is_user_logged_in()){
    die("You Must Be Logged In to Access This");
}
if( ! current_user_can('edit_files')) {
    die("Sorry you are not authorized to access this file");
}
```

However, I'd like a more bulletproof method of specifying the path to `wp-load.php` in case the actual relative path is different than my example.

Comment: Don't. [Use AJAX the proper WordPress way](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: To add to what Milo said, here are 2 great posts on the subject. http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/ ([last version](http://bit.ly/1MvLHNo) )
http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/ ([last version](http://bit.ly/1D5iV30) ) Also for the sake of learning, the first slideshow
http://andrewnacin.com/2011/04/16/wordcamp-seattle/ ([last version](http://bit.ly/1MvLI3R) )

Comment: **You should use a REST API endpoint instead of a standalone file so you get a nice pretty URL and don't have to load/bootstrap WP**. Standalone PHP files like this are a security risk and carry lots of problems

Answer (score 11):

You can use `__DIR__` constant. Since the file is either inside plugin or theme folder, which are always located inside `wp-content` folder.. You can simply get the path of the file and trim everything starting from `wp-content` from it:

```php
$path = preg_replace( '/wp-content.*$/', '', __DIR__ );
```

If you need to make sure the wp is not inside some `wp-content` folder (who knows? things happen) - use negative lookahead:

```php
$path = preg_replace( '/wp-content(?!.*wp-content).*/', '', __DIR__ );
```

(since it's easier to be sure your own plugin you are developing is not located inside some other `wp-content` folder)

Aaand.. your `wp-load` is there:

```php
require_once( $path . 'wp-load.php' );
```

## Best Practice

As before mentioned, for AJAX you should use WordPress' [admin-ajax technique](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or [the new REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Comment: `wp-content` can be absent or in a completely different directory than WP.

Comment: This is probably the best way. If you have a weird wp-content location (unlikely) just adjust your regex.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but wanted to add my own answer which I think might help some users trying to achieve the same thing.

Yes it's always better (and easier) to use the native WP Ajax API, but it can become very slow because it loads the entire WP instance.

**My solution:** is quite simple, and should work to retrieve the `root` of the wordpress installation. In whatever script you are doing the custom AJAX call, just make sure you first register the script with `wp_register_script()` (don't enqueue it yet). Then use `wp_localize_script()` and parse the `ABSPATH` (this is a constant that is defined inside `wp-load.php` and will hold the root path). You can now retrieve this inside your script and parse it along with the AJAX call. Finally of course make sure to actually enqueue the script with `wp_enqueue_script()`.

**Example:**

The below PHP snippet will enqueue your `script.js` file, and allows you to retrieve the `root` dir by calling `pluginslug_scriptname_i18n.wp_root`. Basically the `wp_localize_script()` is used to do translations, but this also becomes in handy to parse data into your script(s) that you retrieved server side.

```
        $handle = 'pluginslug-scriptname'; // Set script handle
        $name = str_replace( '-', '_', $handle ) . '_i18n'; // Will convert handle to pluginslug_scriptname_i18n
        wp_register_script( $handle, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'script.js', array(), '1.0.0', false );  
        wp_localize_script(
            $handle,
            $name,
            array( 
                'ajax_url' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'ajax-handler.php', // @THIS WILL HOLD YOUR AJAX URL :) To retrieve this inside your script.js simply call: pluginslug_scriptname_i18n.ajax_url
                'wp_root' => ABSPATH // @THIS WILL HOLD THE ROOT PATH :) To retrieve this inside your script.js simply call: pluginslug_scriptname_i18n.wp_root
            )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( $handle );
```

Your `script.js` could look like this:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 ){
            if (this.status == 200) {
                // Success:
            }
            // Complete:
        }
    };
    xhttp.onerror = function () {
      console.log(this);
      console.log("** An error occurred during the transaction");
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", pluginslug_scriptname_i18n.ajax_url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    var params = JSON.stringify({
        first_name: 'Johny',
        wp_root: pluginslug_scriptname_i18n.wp_root
    });
    xhttp.send(params);
```

Now inside your `ajax-handler.php` you can retrieve the `wp_content_dir` and load your `wp-load.php` like so:

```
// Set proper content type
header('Content-Type: text/html');
// Disable caching
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
// Get's the payload
$request_body = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input'), true );  

// Set this to true to just load the basics!
// Only set this to true if you know what you are doing
// Lookup SHORTINIT inside wp-settings.php for more details
define( 'SHORTINIT', false ); 

// Include wp-load.php
require_once( $request_body['wp_root'] . 'wp-load.php' );
die();
```

**Please keep in mind that the `wp_root` can be altered client side.**

**As a side note:**

Another trick that some of you might not be aware of is that before including `wp-load.php` you can define a constant called `SHORTINIT` (boolean). This will tell WordPress to just load the basics (meaning you will lose a lot of WP core functions) but it will speed up the loading time since it won't include all the required files for a regular WP instance. The `SHORTINIT` is defined inside `wp-settings.php` (just open up the file and look for `SHORTINIT`. You will have a better understanding of what is happening under the hood. This nifty trick will speed up the load times even more (up to 75% in my tests that I did some time ago). But this will depend on the WP version. Also keep in mind that the `wp-load.php` changes frequently with new releases of WP versions, so if you use `SHORTINIT` be sure that your script will always work even in future versions of WordPress, and also with lower version of WordPress. In short, if you do complex things that rely on a lot of the WordPress codex, then make sure to **NOT** set `SHORTINIT` to **true**.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this as a possible "bulletproof" method of finding the path to `wp-load.php` so long as it is in a directory above where you are running the script.

```
echo get_wp_abspath('wp-load.php') . PHP_EOL;

function get_wp_abspath($filename)
{
  $_DIR = __DIR__; // location of this script

  $_FILE = $_DIR . '/' . $filename; // fullpath/file

  while(!file_exists($_FILE)) // if not found
  {
    $_DIR = dirname($_DIR); // up one step (i.e. ../)

    $_FILE = $_DIR . '/' . $filename; // new fullpath/file

    if($_DIR == '/') return FALSE; // if we hit the base path, fail
  }

  return $_FILE; // if file found, return fullpath/file
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to use wp-load.php to include wp-load from any location

```
require_once( trailingslashit( ABSPATH ) .'wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: But if you've got ABSPATH set and trailingslashit defined then you've probably already included wp-load.